# Best Practices for NavBar Branding in React-Bootstrap / React-Router-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

There is an issue regarding anchor tags in **React Bootstrap** and **React Router**. I was curious on how other people have handled the situation. It is possible to just leave an anchor tag with an href such as `<a href="/">Site Title</a>` and avoid using `IndexLinkContainer`. There is also using MenuItem such as.

```
<Navbar.Brand>
    <IndexLinkContainer to={{pathname: '/'}}>
          <MenuItem>TitleName</MenuItem>
     </IndexLinkContainer>
 </Navbar.Brand>
```

However this leaves a hidious looking bullet point to the far left of the navbar. If anyone else has any ideas on how to tackle this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what I did (with LinkContainer from react-router-bootstrap):

```
        <LinkContainer to="/" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            <Navbar.Brand>
                <span style={{ width: 95 }}>Some text</span>
                <img  src="somesrc" style={{ height:20, float:'right', marginLeft:10 }}/>
            </Navbar.Brand>
        </LinkContainer>
```

Contains site's name and logo.
No bullet point but I couldn't find a way to avoid using LinkContainer..