# Icon in header with meteor react-bootstrap and react-router

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, react-router, react-bootstrap

How to resize the header logo to fit using bootstrap meteor react? I cannot make [specific CSS styling](https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq) work.

The `MainLayout.js` with navigation header looks currently like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteHandler, Link } from 'react-router';
import { Button, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

const MainLayout = ({children}) =>
  <div className='main-layout'>
    <header>
      <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey="1">
        <LinkContainer to="/">
          <NavItem eventKey={1}>
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></img>
          </NavItem>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/Library">
          <NavItem eventKey={2}>Library</NavItem>
        </LinkContainer>
      </Nav>
    </header>
    {children}
```

export default MainLayout;

Answer (score 2):

Try

`<Image responsive src="/logo.png" alt="logo" />` instead of `<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></img>`

or adding `className='img-responsive'` to the `<img>` element

=== EDIT ===

If you want the Nav to behave responsive and keep the brand Icon outside, you need to move it outside your nav component. Here's what I have

```
<Navbar fluid={true}>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <Link to="/"><Image responsive src="/logo.png" alt="logo" /></Link>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav> Element Would Go in here
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>;
```

Comment: note that I'm using react-router with bootstrap, which requires `LinkContainer` objects

Comment: The question was about the resizing of the Image, have you tried the solution to see if the image resizes based on the `responsive` attribute.

Comment: Yes the responsive attribute works! But I cannot get the image to desired size and in line with other header items.

Comment: I found an almost [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41504441/5316326) with an almost sufficient answer to my question; but I think this answer merged with yours is most elegant